# Change "Remove" link text for WooCommerce coupon on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, coupon

Instead of [`Remove`] on the WooCommerce checkout for added coupons, I would like the text to be [`Remove & Re-Calculate`].

I am using the following and the text is changed but there is no link (the coupon cannot be removed).

**This is what I tried:**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 'change_wc_coupon_removal_text', 10, 3 );
function change_wc_coupon_removal_text( $coupon_html, $coupon, $discount_amount_html ) {

    $coupon_html = $discount_amount_html . '<br>' . 'Remove &amp; Re-Calculate';

    return $coupon_html;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[includes/wc-cart-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b612c4f04129c053459e20b5940db544e24eaf5a/includes/wc-cart-functions.php) contains at line 293, just before the `woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html` filter hook.

```php
$coupon_html = $discount_amount_html . ' <a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_coupon', rawurlencode( $coupon->get_code() ), Constants::is_defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT' ) ? wc_get_checkout_url() : wc_get_cart_url() ) ) . '" class="woocommerce-remove-coupon" data-coupon="' . esc_attr( $coupon->get_code() ) . '">' . __( '[Remove]', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
```

So to replace the text, use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon_html, $coupon, $discount_amount_html ) {
    // Change text
    $coupon_html = $discount_amount_html . ' <a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_coupon', rawurlencode( $coupon->get_code() ), defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT' ) ? wc_get_checkout_url() : wc_get_cart_url() ) ) . '" class="woocommerce-remove-coupon" data-coupon="' . esc_attr( $coupon->get_code() ) . '">' . __( '[Remove &amp; Re-Calculate]', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';

    return $coupon_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 10, 3 );
```

**OR**

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon_html, $coupon, $discount_amount_html ) {
    // Change text
    $coupon_html = str_replace( '[Remove]', '[Remove &amp; Re-Calculate]', $coupon_html );

    return $coupon_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 10, 3 );
```